# At column, Count word in comma-separated sentence

Tags: python, database, pandas, count

Supposed my dataframe is

```
  Name  Value
0   K   apple,banana
1   Y   banana
2   B   orange,banana
3   Q   grape,apple
4   C   apple,grape
```

I want to count word in 'Value' column so when I applied like

`pd.Series(np.concatenate([x.split() for x in df.Value])).value_counts()`

`pd.Series(' '.join(df.Value).split()).value_counts()`

as output :

```
apple,banana : 1
banana : 1
orange,banana : 1
grape,apple : 1
apple,grape : 1
```

but

**output what I want**

```
apple : 3
banana : 3
orange : 1
grape : 2
```

How can I do this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Using ` collections.Counter()` should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
df['Value'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
apple     3
banana    3
grape     2
orange    1
dtype: int64
```

Using the `str` accessor for pandas then `split` on ',', `stack` the columns into the row index and use `value_counts`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, assuming `file` contains your input:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('file',sep='\s+')
itemslist=[i.split(',') for i in df['Value'].tolist()]
allitems=[item for sublist in itemslist for item in sublist]

for fruit in [ele for ind, ele in enumerate(allitems,1) if ele not in allitems[ind:]]:
    print("{} {}".format(fruit,allitems.count(fruit)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this in three ways:

- Either you can isolate the column as a list df['col'].tolist() followed by splitting each item in the list. This will give you a list of lists which you would need to flatten and then use collections.Counter on that list
- pandas approach would be to isolate this column and expand it using something like this:
  https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/11/how-to-split-a-text-column-in-pandas/. This can give you a sparse dataframe with all these words. Then you can iterate through all the columns and perform a value_counts on each of those following a merge of these counts. (Scott Boston's answer)
- A third and more pythonic way would be to define a new method that can return a Counter dict for each row and assign this in a new column. Once you have the column containing all the dictionary counts, have a method that can merge those dictionaries in a column and update counts.